# How to produce integer literal as an attribute in Scala XML output?

Tags: xml, scala, xml-literals

I expect the following code to produce XML value with the following content:

```
<TestInteger value="10"/>
```

Compiler gives of an error

```
scala> import scala.xml._
import scala.xml._
scala> val x:Int = 10
x: Int = 10
scala> <TestInteger value={x}/>
<console>:8: error: overloaded method constructor UnprefixedAttribute with alternatives (String,Option[Seq[scala.xml.Node]],scala.xml.MetaData)scala.xml.UnprefixedAttribute <and> (String,String,scala.xml.MetaData)scala.xml.UnprefixedAttribute <and> (String,Seq[scala.xml.Node],scala.xml.MetaData)scala.xml.UnprefixedAttribute cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,Int,scala.xml.MetaData)
       <TestInteger value={x}/>
```

What am I doing wrong? Are integer literals allowed in XML?

I'm using Scala 2.7.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look like your XML is violating XML specification according to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-EntityValue) each attribute value must begin with a double quote. See AttValue rule.
**Edit**:
After some googling around it seems that [scala.xml.UnprefixedAttribute](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/scala/xml/UnprefixedAttribute.html) has Constructor that only supports strings as values so since there is no build-in implicit conversion from Int's to String this code of yours will not work same as code :

```
val a : String = 10
```

Scala doesn't now how convert integers to strings automatically but following code however will work

```
implicit def intToString(i:Int) = i.toString  
val a : Int = 10
val b  = <Test attr={a}/>
```

Comment: Then again schema allows integer values nevertheless (I'll give up on quotes, but still want to treat an argument as integer. http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_XML_21days&seqNum=71

Answer (score 1):

Scala XML has no support for any type other than `String`. One *can* extend the library to add alternatives to `Text`, but, as it is, there's no support.

Comment: That is wrong. Scala XML does only support `String` values in attributes but supports any type for nodes! `<tag>{ 5 }</tag>` will compile. The integer literal `5` will be encapsuled in an `Atom[Int]`. That works for all types!

Comment: @Martin Mmmmm. I thought `Atom` was abstract, the only subclasses being `Text`, `Unparsed` and `PCData`.

Comment: Atom is not abstract (See [api](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.8.1/scala/xml/Atom.html)) .

    `scala> val xml = <tag>{ 42 }</tag>`
    `xml: scala.xml.Elem = <tag>42</tag>`
    
    `scala> xml.child(0).isInstanceOf[scala.xml.Atom[Int]]`
    `res0: Boolean = true`

Comment: @Martin I noticed that after your comment, but I thought it wasn't before. By the way, `Int` there is not checked, as it is type erased. Yes, it is an `Atom`, but so would be a `Text`.

Comment: You can still get the `Int` or any other object out of the `Atom` because it is stored in the `data` field of  `Atom[T]`. So it is different from `Text(42.toString)`